# FULL TEXT SEARCH in cakephp ? any example

Tags: full-text-search, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am using ordinary search functionality in my business controller . but 
now need to implement FULL TEXT SEARCH with paginate can any one give idea or sample ?
I am using MySQL with MyISAM tabes

and this my table structure, fields marked bold are need to use in 
search

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS businesses ( 
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  created date NOT NULL, 
  modified datetime NOT NULL, 
  user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  slug varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  **`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,** 
  **street_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,** 
  **shopping_center varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,** 
  state_id int(10) NOT NULL, 
  suburb_id int(10) NOT NULL, 
  zip_code varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL, 
  website varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL, 
  email varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
  phone_no varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  mobile_no varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
  fax varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
  is_active tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After you have [created your `FULLTEXT` indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) it's not different at all from normal paginate conditions, you just need to construct your SQL a little more manually and most importantly **escape the user input manually**.

```php
$query = 'foobar'; // the user input to search for
$escapedQuery = $this->Business->getDataSource()->value($query);

$this->paginate['conditions'] = array("MATCH (Business.name) AGAINST ($escapedQuery)");
$businesses = $this->paginate();
```

Comment: If I need to used multiple fields such as name and street_name and shopping_center ???

Comment: [Read the documentation for `MATCH ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) and construct your indices and queries accordingly.

Comment: Yes got it . Thanks i find a solution