# I am trying to paginate the search results and display it on the template's view file using CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, search, pagination

This is the controller file where the all the search results are coming from the `foreach` loop , I tried paginating it, but can't figure out how to do it.

```
<?php
class SerController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $check_string=$this->request->data('check');
        $check_break=explode(" ",$check_string);
        $s1=TableRegistry::get('ser_tab');
        foreach($check_break as $check)
        {
            $s11=$s1->find('all')->where(['OR' =>['text LIKE' => '%'.$check.'%','name LIKE' => '%'.$check.'%']]);
            $this->set(array('data' => $s11)); 
        }                
        $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use mysql **full text search** http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/18/advanced-text-searching-using-full-text-indexes

Comment: With pagination have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/6184178/3278789

Answer (score 0):

Your query will take too long execution time. You can do it simply.
Update your `index()` function like as below

**Example [When data from URL]**

```
public function index($data='Default text here'){ /*When get Data from the URL*/
    $data = explode(' ', $data);
    $conditions = array(); /*All OR conditions will store here*/

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $conditions['or'][] = array('text LIKE' => "%$value%");
        $conditions['or'][] = array('name LIKE' => "%$value%");
    }

    $this->paginate = [
        'limit' => 25, #Set the limit of post
        'conditions'=>[
            $conditions /*OR conditions array*/
        ]
    ];

    $data = $this->paginate();
    var_dump($conditions,$data);            /*Debug OR Condition array and Query data*/
    $this->set(compact('data'));            /*Set the Posts to a variable*/
}
```

**Example [When data from POST]**

```
public function index(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data('check');
        # YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

CakePHP 3.x pagination documentation is [HERE](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html)

Comment: Or just use a proper PRG pattered [Search](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) plugin for it ;) Solved properly and without so much code in the controller scope.

Comment: is it possible to add pagination without the model, and just by using controller and the view

Comment: Yes! You can Direct Use Paginator components. Like `$this->Paginator->paginate(YOUR_QUERY_OBJECT, CONFIGS)` Here is the Details (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-the-paginator-directly) @HarjeevSingh

Comment: Conditions array. Example : `array('limit'=10,'conditions'=>array('Your condition is here'))` @Harjeev